# SQL: How do I convert nvarchar to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, datetime

I'm having trouble to convert `nvarchar(4000)` to `date(103)`

I have tried:

```
select convert(date,[column1],103) from #temptable
select convert(datetime,[column1],103) from #temptable
select cast([column1] as date) from #temptable
select cast([column1] as datetime) from #temptable

select cast(convert(char,[column1],8) as datetime) from #temptable
select cast(convert(float,[column1]) as datetime) from #temptable
```

My column1 consist of 700000 different dates, they looks 20200309 (yyyymmdd)

And all of them gave me same error message:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

or

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yyyymmdd` is a safe and unambiguous date format for SQL Server, so this  should just work:

```
convert(date, column1)
```

The fact that you are getting errors indicates that you have wrongly formatted data. You can exhibit the offending values with `try_convert()` like that:

```
select column1
from #temptable
where column1 is not null and try_convert(date, column1) is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, [column1], 103) FROM #temptable
```

OR

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, [column1], 103) FROM #temptable
```